# error: No matching function for call to my class object

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction

Maybe I am initializing it incorrectly? Preety sure this is how our teacher showed us how to do it.. but im stumped. I am trying to use the function as an accessor and get the data and display what is already stored in the struct "coordinate" under the member "Entrance"

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include "type.h"
const int MAX = 50;
#ifndef MazeClass_H
#define MazeClass_H

class MazeClass
{
    private:
        SquareType Maze[MAX][MAX];
        coordinate      Entrance, Exit;
        int     height, width;
    public:
        MazeClass();
        void    ReadMaze(ifstream&);
        void    DisplayMaze();
        void    GetEntrance(coordinate);
        void    GetExit(coordinate);
        void    MarkVisited(coordinate);
        void    MarkPath(coordinate);
        bool    IsWall(coordinate);
        bool    IsClear(coordinate);
        bool    IsPath(coordinate);
        bool    IsVisited(coordinate);
        bool    IsExit(coordinate);
        bool    IsInMaze(coordinate);
};
#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "MazeClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

char maze[50][50];
MazeClass::MazeClass()
{
}

void MazeClass::ReadMaze(ifstream& myIn)
{
    int x, y;
    myIn >> x;
    myIn >> y;
    height = x;
    width = y;
    myIn >> x;
    myIn >> y;
    Entrance.row = x;
    Entrance.col = y;
    myIn >> x;
    myIn >> y;
    Exit.row = x;
    Exit.col = y;
    myIn.ignore(100, '\n');
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < width + 1; k++)
        {
            myIn.get(maze[i][k]);
            if(maze[i][k] == '*')
                Maze[i][k] == Wall;
            else
                Maze[i][k] == Clear;
        }
    }
}

void MazeClass::DisplayMaze()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < width + 1; k++)
        {
            cout << maze[i][k];
        }
    }
}

void MazeClass::GetEntrance(coordinate Entrance)
{
}

void MazeClass::GetExit(coordinate Exit)
{
}
```

and my file to try and use it:

```
#include "MazeClass.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    MazeClass maze;
    ifstream myIn;
    int x,y;
    string filename = argv[1]; // command line arguement stuff

    myIn.open(filename.c_str());
    maze.ReadMaze(myIn); //reads in the maze from a data file
    maze.DisplayMaze();
    cout << "The entrance is at: " << maze.GetEntrance().row << " " << maze.GetEntrance.col << endl;
    myIn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

and im getting this error:

```
ola4A1.cc:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘MazeClass::GetEntrance()’
MazeClass.h:21: note: candidates are: void MazeClass::GetEntrance(coordinate)
ola4A1.cc:17: error: ‘maze.MazeClass::GetEntrance’ does not have class type
```

I have tried placing coordinate in like this:

```
#include "MazeClass.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    MazeClass maze;
    ifstream myIn;
    int x,y;
    string filename = argv[1]; // command line arguement stuff

    myIn.open(filename.c_str());
    maze.ReadMaze(myIn); //reads in the maze from a data file
    maze.DisplayMaze();
    cout << "The entrance is at: " << maze.GetEntrance(coordinate).row << " " << maze.GetEntrance(coordinate).col << endl;
    myIn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

but i THEN get the error:

```
ola4A1.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

AFTER which... I added in "Entrance" like so..

```
#include "MazeClass.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    MazeClass maze;
    ifstream myIn;
    int x,y;
    string filename = argv[1]; // command line arguement stuff

    myIn.open(filename.c_str());
    maze.ReadMaze(myIn); //reads in the maze from a data file
    maze.DisplayMaze();
    cout << "The entrance is at: " << maze.GetEntrance(coordinate Entrance).row << " " << maze.GetEntrance(coordinate Entrance).col << endl;
    myIn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

and it gives me this error...

```
ola4A1.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘Entrance’
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘Entrance’
```

So YES... I am stumped...Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have been trying to figure this one out for an hour now :(

Comment: The error messages (you get 2 errors and 1 note) are quite informative... Your call to `MazeClass::GetEntrance` e.g. `maze.GetEntrance()` is missing some argument. What don't you understand in them?

Comment: maze.GetEntrance() returns void, not structure coordinate . so you cant access like this maze.GetEntrance().row. An argument is needed to call function GetEntrance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to  acces member variables of variable `Entrance`  in main. i think what you need is this

```
coordinate MazeClass::GetEntrance()
{
   return Entrance;
}
```

And change you function prototype in header file accordingly.

With this modification your below statement will work fine (check `()` for calling `col`)

```
cout << "The entrance is at: " << maze.GetEntrance().row << " " << maze.GetEntrance().col << endl;
```

Change your `GetExit` function also like this for using it

Comment: Perfect!! The void was messing me up. I was forsure I needed it set as void. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The error message actually tells you what is wrong:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MazeClass::GetEntrance()’
                                                              ^^^^^
```

The function you have provided is:

```
void MazeClass::GetEntrance(coordinate Entrance)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the `^^^^^^` in above.

As you see both functions are not same!
You declared and defined a method which takes `coordinate` object as parameter but you are calling a method which does not take any argument, obviously the compiler does not find any such method and complains appropriately.

Comment: When I put (coordinate Entrance) into the function call in my .cc file it gives me this error           ola4A1.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘Entrance’
ola4A1.cc:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘Entrance’

Comment: @JohnSmith: *you really are not understanding the basics of programming and of C++*. You should not ask questions here before having understood them (because teaching C++ takes a lot of time, and we don't have that much on SO). Go into your university's library, and **take many hours to read good books on programming in C++** .... Trying to code something "randomly" and hoping that it will work by chance is not the good route to learning programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `GetEntrance` says that it expects an parameter (of type `coordinate`).

Where you try to call it, you aren't passing a parameter, so it's looking for some other overload that can be called without a parameter.

Also note that your `maze.GetEntrance.col` probably needs to be `maze.GetEntrance().col` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1) You are calling `maze.GetEntrance()`, but `MazeClass` has no `GetEntrance()` method. There is only `MazeClass::GetEntrance(coordinate)`.

2) Your call to `maze.GetEntrance().row` suggests you expect `MazeClass::GetENtrance()` to return something. It currently returns `void`, and `void` has no member `row`.